# Modify colletion using entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my project I have bellow Entity class

```
public partial class Movie
{
public Movie()
{
this.MovieCategories = new HashSet<MovieCategory>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MovieCategory> MovieCategories { get; set; }
}

public partial class MovieCategory
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public int MovieId { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
public virtual Movie Movie{ get; set; }
}


public partial class Category
{
public Category()
{
    this.MovieCategories = new HashSet<MovieCategory>();
}
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Category1 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MovieCategory> MovieCategories { get; set; }
```

}

I have view where I can add or remove "MovieCategories" using listbox.

Bellow is how I am trying to update my movie object using entityframework.

```
    _movieReviewEntities.Movies.Attach(movie);
    _movieReviewEntities.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _movieReviewEntities.SaveChanges();
```

This is updating "Id", "Name" & "Description" properties but not updating my colletion "MovieCategories"

How can I update "MovieCategories" also ?

Comment: Do you want to load `MovieCategories` relation from database and update `movie` object or you want to update databases' values with your local values?

Comment: @astef I want to update database with local values

Comment: How do you create the "movie" object or how do you instantiate it?

Comment: @DeathWish I have edit view where I can edit values & select multiple categories for movie

Comment: You code is no sufficient to understand the issue. We can see a movie class. Is it an Entity in your database or a ViewModel?

Comment: it is an entity class. Also "MovieCategory" is also an entity class

Comment: We cannot see how you are modifying the MovieCategory entity. In you database, which one is the parent and which one is the child? Think about it when you accept a solution. You cannot delete parents before deleting children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have a new MovieCategory and you want to update a Movie with this new MovieCategory.

Please take note that I didn't test this.

```
MovieCategory newCategory = new MovieCategory
{
   "Action Movie"
};

movie.MovieCategories.Add(newCategory);

_movieReviewEntities.Movies.Attach(movie);
_movieReviewEntities.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
_movieReviewEntities.SaveChanges();
```

This should also add the new movie category.

In case your category exists in your table

```
var existingCategory = _movieReviewEntities.MovieCategories.Where(m => m.Name == "Action Movie")
.Select(m => m).FirstOrDefault();

if(existingCategory != null)
{
   movie.MovieCategories.Add(existingCategory);
}
```

If you have for a example a ListBox that contains the selected movie categories.

```
//From ListBox
var fromSelection = new List<string>("Comedy", "Drama");

//Fetch from table
var categoryListToAdd = movie.MovieCategories.Where(x => fromSelection.Contains(x.Name)).Select(x => x).ToList();

if(categoryListToAdd.Count > 0)
{
    //Existing categories of the movie.
    var categoryList = movie.MovieCategories.Select(x => x).ToList();


    //Remove the related records.
    if(categoryList.Count > 0)
       categoryList.ForEach(x => _movieReviewEntities.MovieCategories.Remove(x));

    //Then add the selected categories. 
    categoryListToAdd.ForEach(x => _movieReviewEntities.Add(x));
}
```

Again, this is not tested. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: what about existing moviecategories present already for Movie ? i.e. lets say I have movie object with movie category Action",  Now I want to remove moviecategory "Action" & add moviecategory "Comedy". How this will be done ?

Comment: what version of EF you are using?

Comment: .RemoveRange and .AddRange would do instead of iterating.

Answer (score 0):

To modify relation in EF context, both related objects should be tracked by the context. It means that you must attach both `Movie` and `MovieCategory` objects to a context to modify a relation between them.

By the way, if you load entities, they remain attached in context. Here's a simple example how you can load a movie with it's categories and clear all categories and add a new one:

```
using (var context = new MovieContext())
{
    var movie = context.Movies.Include(m => m.MovieCategories).First(m => m.Name == "Green Elephant");
    movie.MovieCategories.Clear();
    var newCategory = context.MovieCategories.Create();
    newCategory.Name = "Trash";
    movie.MovieCategories.Add(newCategory);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```